# How to check if there are any matches between two lists of sublists using regular expressions?

Tags: python, regex, list, sublist

I have two lists of sublists and I want to check if one item in the sublists in both lists match the other list?

For example, I'd like to see if any sublist at index 0 occurs within the other list at index 0

```
lsta = [['aaa','bbb','ccc'],['xxx','bbb','ccc'],['eee','bbb','ccc']]
lstb = [['aaa','b','2'],['xxx','ddd','efe']]
```

What's the fastest way to return all items in lsta if any of the items at index one occur at index 1 in lstb? :

```
Desired_List = [['aaa','bbb','ccc'],['xxx','bbb','ccc']]
```

For-Loops are too slow for my large list, so I'm wondering if there is a faster method?

This is essentially the task I'm trying to accomplish, but faster

```
Desired_List = []
for x in lsta:
    for y in lstb:
        if re.search(x[0],str(y)):
            Desired_List.append(x)
```

or is there any other way to accomplish this task? Perhaps a list comprehension?

Also, perhaps, but not sure if anything faster:

```
   Desired_List = filter(lambda x: re.search(str(x[0]),str(lstb)),lsta)
```

Comment: Can you post your for-loop?

Note that this is an n^2 algorithm (each element in lsta needs to be compared against each element of lstb), although if you're doing lots of executions, you may be able to speed it up with better data structures.

Comment: how could i improve the data structure here?

Answer (score 2):

Make a `set` of the items that appear at index 0 of sublists of `lstb`, then use the set to quickly determine items of `lsta` that match:

```
b_set = set(sublist[0] for sublist in lstb)
desiredlist = [sublist for sublist in lsta if sublist[0] in b_set]
```

Note that your `for` loop solution is wrong:

```
>>> lsta = [[', ', '', '']]
>>> lstb = [['a', 'b', 'c']]
>>> Desired_List = []
>>> for x in lsta:
...     for y in lstb:
...         if re.search(x[0],str(y)):
...             Desired_List.append(x)
...
>>> Desired_List
[[', ', '', '']]
```

Comment: @Chris: Corrected and tested.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to speed this up by building a dict out of `lstb`:

```
dictb = {el[0]: el for el in lstb}
Desired_List = [el for el in lsta if el[0] in dictb]
```